# Mock ElementRef and getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: typescript, jestjs

How to mock ElementRef and getBoundingClientRect()

I tried the follow but didn`t work.

```
const hostRefMock = {
    nativeElement: {
        getBoundingClientRect: {top: 10, left: 10}
    }
}

{provide: ElementRef, useFactory: () => hostRefMock}
```

Comment: You should provide it as a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const hostRefMock = {
  nativeElement: {
    getBoundingClientRect: () => ({ top: 10, left: 10 }),
  },
};

{ provide: ElementRef, useFactory: () => hostRefMock }
```

Comment: It returns 0 for all properties

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you're using ElementRef and getBoundingClientRect() in the component or service you're testing?

Comment: this worked: window.HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = () => ({top: 10, left: 10} as DOMRect)